# AWS SecretManager CLI list-secrets - sort secrets by Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-secrets-manager

I am using aws cli to get a list of secrets. However, I wanted them to be sorted by name. I am not sure how does AWS CLI sort it. The command I am using is:

```
aws secretsmanager list-secrets --sort-order desc
```

Is there a way to sort the output by Name or ARN ?

Answer (score 2):

--sort-order should be sorting on Name, however you can also use sort_by in a query to accomplish this against different fields as well.

Examples:

```
aws secretsmanager list-secrets --query 'sort_by(SecretList, &Name)[]'

aws secretsmanager list-secrets --query 'sort_by(SecretList, &ARN)[]'

aws secretsmanager list-secrets --query 'sort_by(SecretList, &LastChangedDate)[]'
```

Of note - both ways are client-side sorting, so if the call returns more than the max-items or page-size, it will only sort the results returned by the call.